# Database lock Sqlite multiple Threads

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, sqlite

I'm programming an C# application with a SQLite database, I get the message: `Database Locked(5)` in my output log sometimes. I don't want that to happen, I know that multiple actions performed to my database give me this exception.

**Question:**

Is there a way to see if the SQLiteDatabase is busy processing other queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're creating a multithreaded application, having the knowledge you ask for will not solve any problems. They might make them appear less often, but occasionally you will see the same problem as before.

Why? Because from the instant where you ask "are you locked?" to the instant where you say "in that case, let me lock you to do something", another thread might have jumped in and locked it.

Unless you get a timeout, I would handle the exceptions and determine in each case what to do.

Additionally, since SQLite is inherently a single-user (and not user as in person, but user as in "something that uses the database") database, you might consider that this is not growing to be the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, no it is the almost perfect Database for my Application, I think I need to use a bool to check whether something is only trying to send a query to the database, and at the moment that it is, I could use that bool to prevent other Threads to send a query to the database, one problem, when the bool has been set to something like: busy = false again, it should immediately execute the "Tasks"(query's to the database) when it has the time. Any way to achieve that using a while loop?

Comment: What you are looking for is a Compare and Swap.  C# has one in the Interlocked class  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801kt583%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  The other thing you could use is a Mutex